# How compiler treat the initializer_list of vector<Type> which <Type> have multi parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

```
class Complex{
public:
    Complex(int a, int b): real(a), imag(b){}
    ~Complex(){}
private:
    int real;
    int imag;

};

int main()
{
    vector<Complex> vec1 {1,2,3,4}; //Why can't be recognize in C++11
    vector<Complex> vec2 {{1,2},{4,6}};

}
```

Look the codes above, I define a class Complex, it need 2 param in constructor. Then I define 2 vector, why vec1 cannot be recognized, the complier cannot treat it as vec1{ {1,2}, {3,4} }?

Comment: The short answer is because C++ does not work this way.

Comment: Too much potential for confusions even among humans. To the casual reader is that supposed to be (1,0), (2,0), (3,0), (4,0)? (1,2), (3,4)? The second one forces you to write exactly what you mean and that is worth it's weight in gold.

Comment: but actually, the Complex constructor need 2 parameters, I told the vector the type is <Complex>, Why cannot the complier allocate {1,2} to Complex1, {3,4} to Complex2 in vec1?

Comment: Trying arbitrary combinations until you find one with which the code compiles is not the behavior most people want from the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector<Complex> v{1, 2, 3, 4}` is a statement that tries to pass an `initailizer_list<int>` into your vector's construction. This is, obviously, an error. When you use `{ {1, 2}, {3, 4} }` instead, it coaxes the initializer list to construct a set of `Complex` classes to pass into your vector.

Comment: I do not believe that your first claim is true.

Comment: `v{1, 2, 3, 4}` does not try to construct the vector with `initializer_list<int>`. First preference is given to the vector's `initializer_list<Complex>` constructor but that is not a match because a `Complex` cannot be constructed from each argument in the braced-init-list. Once that fails, the remaining `vector<Complex>` constructors are enumerated, none of those are matches either, and compilation fails.

Comment: I agree with Praetorian.

    Complex(int a, int b=0): real(a), imag(b){}

if I write constructor like this, give a default to imag, Then the vec1 is valid, all the element is {1,0},{2,0},{3,0},{4,0},
absolutely , it went into the Complex constructor.

But I just wondering why the complier won't allocate the first 2 argument {1,2} to Complex constructor, like Complex(1,2).